# Get Value from 2 div using same class / id

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically created div like below

First DIV :

```
<div class="page_of_pagination pagination_filter_bar" style=""> 2 found</div>
```

Second DIV :

```
<div class="page_of_pagination pagination_filter_bar" style=""> 2 found</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to get both div value.. how its possible

I Tried Using the below code..

```
alert($(".page_of_pagination").find(0).text());
```

Please note i don't want to use `.each` function jQuery i want to directly call like

```
$(".page_of_pagination"[0].text()
```

Not exactly like above but i need to call like that

Comment: What do you mean by value?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How do you wish to retrieve it (value anyway doesn't mean anything when it comes to DIVs)? User interaction or what?

Comment: `alert($(".page_of_pagination").eq(0).text());` will work but now that depends when/how you call it too because basically you said: "I have a dynamically created div"...

Comment: Looks like you should really read some basic tutos...

Comment: @RGraham i mean its html / its text

Comment: it is a text. you can use `.text()` for this. If you want to get the inner html, you can use `.html()`.

Comment: @CJRamki Is right, these are two different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you'd like to target each element individually...

```
$('.page_of_pagination.pagination_filter_bar').eq(0).text();
$('.page_of_pagination.pagination_filter_bar').eq(1).text();
```

https://api.jquery.com/eq

Comment: `$('.page_of_pagination pagination_filter_bar')`?  Wrong selector.

Answer (score 3):

You can user [jQuery's each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for this:

```
$('.page_of_pagination').each(function(){
    alert( $(this).text() ); // if you want the content as text
    // alert( $(this).html() ); // If you want the content as html
});
```

*This is very simple, you should be ablt to find this kind of info yourself. I suggest browsing through the [jQuery's website](http://api.jquery.com/), to see what functions they have*

---

**After your 'one by one'-edit:**
If you want them selected one by one:

```
$('.page_of_pagination').eq(0).text();
$('.page_of_pagination').eq(1).text();
```

I'm not sure why you want this, you might have a valid reason, but keep in mind you want as much as possible automated. If you make a third option, you dont want to keep updating your code. The `.each()` function has a index function if you want the `i`-like value in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, was working on one myself. Integrated the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 $('.page_of_pagination').each(function(){
    alert( $(this).html() );
 });
```